# I am receiving a semi colon error expected in pascal

Tags: compiler-errors, user-input, calculator, compiler-warnings, pascal

```
program Hello;
const
Allowance =  0.05 ;
Deduction = 0.215 ;
Com1 = 0.1 ;
Com2 = 0.05 ; 
ComReq = 8000.00;

var
 
 Running : Boolean ;
 Nameemp : char ;
 Pos : char ;
 BasicSalary : real ;
 Salary : real ;
 Code : char ;
 AllAmt : real ;
 DedAmt :  real ;
 GrossIncome : real ;
 TotalSales : real ;
 ComAmt : real ;
 Enter : integer ; 

 


begin
  Running := TRUE ;
  GrossIncome := 0 ;
  while Running = TRUE  do 
  
      writeln ('please input employees name' );
      readln(Nameemp);
      writeln ('please input employees position' );
      readln(Pos);
      writeln ('enter employee’s category code');
      readln(Code);
      writeln('please enter the employees basic salary');
      readln(BasicSalary);
      AllAmt := BasicSalary * Allowance;
      DedAmt := BasicSalary * Deduction;
      GrossIncome := BasicSalary + AllAmt;
      Salary := GrossIncome - DedAmt;
      if Code = 'SS' then 
        begin
        writeln ('please enter employees total sales for the month');
        readln(TotalSales);
        if TotalSales >= ComReq then 
            begin
            ComAmt := com1 * TotalSales ;
            end
        else 
            begin
            ComAmt := com2*TotalSales ;
            end
        Salary := Salary + ComAmt;
        end
      else 
        begin
        writeln('employee is not applicable for a commision')
        end
      writeln(Nameemp);
      writeln(Position);
      writeln(GrossIncome);
      writeln(Salary);
      if Code = 'SS' then 
            begin
            writeln(ComAmt);
            end
      writeln('would you like to run the program again. Enter 1 for yes and enter 2 for no');
      readln(Enter);
      if Enter = 2 then 
        begin
        Running := FALSE;
        end
      
end.
```

In the code above, the error 'main.pas(51,9) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "identifier SALARY" found' keeps showing up and I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me. The program is supposed to take inputs about the name, position salary etc. It then calculates gross income and net income etc and prints the results. the compiler I used is  https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_bash_shell compiler

Comment: There's a semilcolon missing after the `end` on the previous line.

Comment: I found the problem, You have to put semi colons on end. Thanks for helping

Comment: You are also missing a begin end block on the while... Seems you have learned Python before. Indentation works differently in Pascal. You always need begin end blocks. Also in Pascal we usually don't indent the begin and end but only indent the statements within begin and end

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up the indentation a bit for the relevant section of your code, we can see that the second to last `end` is missing a semicolon to separate it from `Salary := Salary + ComAmt`.

```
if Code = 'SS' then 
begin
  writeln ('please enter employees total sales for the month');
  readln(TotalSales);
  if TotalSales >= ComReq then 
  begin
    ComAmt := com1 * TotalSales ;
  end
  else 
  begin
    ComAmt := com2*TotalSales ;
  end
  Salary := Salary + ComAmt;
end
```